# Conversão de Site ou Sistema PHP ou HTML para aplicativo Android e iOS

Tags: php, android, ios, app

Qual a melhor maneira de se 'converter' um site ou sistema PHP ou HTML para um **Aplicativo Android e iOS** ?

Tenho um Script em PHP com DB MySQL e site em HTML , e ouvi falar que dá para gerar com isso a versão do site ou sistema em PHP ou HTML para aplicativo Android e iOS.

O que indicam.?

Answer (score 4):

Nesse caso, você deve criar um app com o recurso de **WebView** para exibir seu sistema PHP hospedado na web.
Existe uma plataforma gratuíta online para criar apps. É bem intuitiva, nem precisa saber Java para programar, você faz tudo montando diagramas de bloco. Muito interessante!
http://appinventor.mit.edu/

Comment: OK, mas dessa forma o App Criado só vai fazer a vês do Browser !